# Undecidable statements and Hypercomputation

Tags: logic, computability

Good day everybody, 
I would love to ask You a question about proving undecidable statements with hypercomputation.

I have read a paper written by Professor T. Ord named "Hypercomputation: computing more than the Turing machine", where he writes this: 
" While it is sometimes claimed [4, 10] that Chaitin constant is completely patternless, this is not true. If it was, it would not be so easily describable. "
" Chaitin’s results about W show not that some mathematical objects are patternless, but that they seem patternless relative to a certain amount of computational power23. The results do not show that some facts (such as the value of a particular bit of W) are true for no reason, but that a certain level of computational power is insufficient to show why these facts are true "

And this is what I would like to ask You about.

Lets for example assume that the Rieman Hypothesis(RH) is undecidable by Turing machine. Therefore there is no finite proof that would prove that RH is true. Can it be said that for us finite beeings the RH is true for no reason at all, or more precisely for unknown reason, but If we had computational capacity of a sufficiently powerful Hypercomputer we would be able to constructively prove with a proof of infinite length that RH is true?

And by this proof I don´t mean just brute forcing this problem away like computing the zeta function for all reals and look for counter example. I mean a proof more in a sense of some inaccessible uncomputable structure, that would lead to a proof for RH much like for example the use of Eliptic curves lead Professor Wiles to a proof of Fermats Last Theorem.

So basically my question is, whether there are mathematical structures or patterns that would explain, why undecidable/non-recursive functions are true.

Thank You very much for your kind answers,
Have a nice day.

Comment: Proofs must always be finite. An infinite string cannot be a proof of some statement, as the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: The definition of "patternless" is based on Turing machines. The Church hypothesis claims that everything that is computable in the intuitive sense, can be realized by a Turing machine. This is only a hypothesis, but a very well backed up one. If we claim that Chaitin's conatant is not patternless after all, we must find an algorithm determining its digits. We know that a Turing machine cannot do this, hence such an algorithm must transcendent the turing machines. Hence we also claim that the Church hypothesis is false.

Comment: If the Riemann hypothesis is false, there must be a counterexample, and in this case, there of course is a turing machine calculating it. Hence, if we could actually show that we cannot solve the problem with turing machines, we would have proven it. But if the Riemann hypothesis is true, there might be no turing machine able to prove this.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion here between two quite different meanings of "undecidable". A problem (with infinitely many particular instances, like the halting problem) is said to be undecidable if there is no (single) algorithm that correctly answers all instances of the problem. A statement (like RH) is said to be undecidable in some axiomatic theory if that theory neither proves nor disproves the statement. Notice, in particular, that the first of these two notions (unlike the second) doesn't presuppose any particular axiomatic system and doesn't mention proofs.